# Is there some debug tools to show the result in a flat table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2008

I want to ask if there 's some debug tools to show the result in a flat table to facilitate finding any logical errors .

For Example ::

[image]

Now I want to see all these rows in a flat table instead of each one through the debugger .

Is there any tool like `LINQPad` for example for this purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger of Visual Studio has already a builtin `DataTable` visualizer. Just click on the loupe-symbol and you can inspect it as table.

If you don't analyze a `DataTable` but a `DataRowCollection`(as in  your screen shot), you can use this in the quick-watch-window of the debugger:

```
rows.Cast<DataRow>().CopyToDataTable()
```

After you have executed it there, you're able to click on the loupe to inspect the table. That works also with a `Linq` query or a `Rows` property of a `DataTable`.

[**Dataset Visualizer Dialog Box**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d480bk47.aspx)

Comment: Could u help me what 's the `loupe-symbol`?

Comment: @just_name: Just right-click on your DataTable. Click quick-watch, then there's a magnifying glass icon that appears next to the Value. Maybe you need to select it first from the list(there's an arrow-down icon besides).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this 's exactly what i want :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an existing tool to show a DataRowCollection in a table form - but generally, these types of tools are called Visualizers. [Here is the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on them - including a link on how to build your own. It's really very straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is not (none that I know of) but you can actually write your own debugging extension. It is not that hard.

THe main problem here is more the use of a DataTable, which is slow, a memory hog and in general worse than real ojects.

Comment: The main problem is that you assume to know the exact constraints laid upon him by the project, its requirements, and the discussions that preceeded the desicion making. We dont know why he did what he did and chastising for a decision that may well not have even been his is quite frankly, off topic